# Create temporary zip folder for JUnit 5 testing

Tags: java, junit5

I have to test some classes that manipulates text files directly inside a zip file. I've thought to create a temporary zip file for JUnit testing and write some specific text files to see the behavior of the classes.
I've only seen how to create temporary directory with @TempDir, but not a temporary zip file.

My question :
Is it possible to create a temporary zip file in JUnit 5 and write some files on it ?

Answer (score 1):

I would look at the [zip4j](http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/) library.

1. Make a directory with the files you want (in a @Before annotated method in your test class)
2. Zip the directory (in the same @Before annotated method)
3. Execute your code you want to test
4. Delete the zip file (in an @After annotated method in your test class)

Comment: I like your approach, very logical! +1 Also, very glad for sharing this library with us. @Connor

Comment: Thank you for this, but how can I delete the zip file after it has been created ? Even if I do "file.delete()", it's still here.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at this simple example how to create a temporary folder( and files within ) and how to write some content to it.

```
public class JUnitExamplesTest{

    private byte[] bytesOfPoem;
    private byte[] bytesOfText;

    // make sure we create temp folder before anything else...
    @Rule
    public TemporaryFolder folder = new TemporaryFolder();
    // zip file
    public File zipFile;

    // now after temp folder has been created deals with creation of a zip file and content within.
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws IOException {
        // some poem
        String poem = "Roses are red, violets are blue...";
        // some message
        String secretMessage = "Life is beautiful.";
        // turn to bytes in order to write them to zip content entries
        bytesOfPoem = poem.getBytes();
        bytesOfText = secretMessage.getBytes();
        // create a zip file zipFile.7z
        zipFile = folder.newFile("zipFile.7z"); 
        // open streams for writing to zip file
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
        ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(out);
        // create entry for poem
        ZipEntry poemEntry = new ZipEntry("/poem.txt");
        // set size for poem entry
        poemEntry.setSize(bytesOfPoem.length);
        // stream entry declaration
        zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(poemEntry);
        // and content within
        zipOutputStream.write(bytesOfPoem);
        ZipEntry messageEntry = new ZipEntry("/Directory/text.txt");
        messageEntry.setSize(bytesOfText.length);
        zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(messageEntry);
        zipOutputStream.write(bytesOfText);
        zipOutputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, however I don't know how to delete the zip file in an @After anotated method. Also, I think that this is for JUnit4, so it will not work for JUnit5.

Comment: JUnit Vintage module of JUnit5 allows us running JUnit4 on JUnit5 platform without any problem! As for folder removal, since it's TemporaryFolder, after tests are conducted, JUnit deletes it and all content within by itself. You can test it in AfterClass annotation if you would like. @Spn

Comment: The question is about JUnit 5 (implicitly JUnit Jupiter), not JUnit 4. I therefore recommend that you delete your answer or convert it to a JUnit Jupiter 5.4 answer.

Comment: JUnit Vintage module is part of JUnit5 therefore I am not going to change the answer. This will work on JUnit5 platform! If he said to go explicitly with JUnit5 testing and use Jupiter module I would, therefore your comment gives me nothing but "I am right and here comes -1! attitude which is well, deeply wrong. @SamBrannen